# Firebird Stored Procedure Token Unknown -end

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

I am very new in writing stored procedures in Firebird and I wrote whatever I see in internet but I am getting Token unknown error. Here is my very simple code

```sql
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE TRIAL
 (
 IN_ID DCOUNTER
 )
  AS

begin
    SELECT * FROM table1
end
```

And the error is:

> Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 13, column 1
> end

How can I fix this? I tried adding and deleting some semicolons, ends, begins.

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure has two syntax errors:

1. Missing semicolon.
2. Missing INTO clause of SELECT query which is mandatory in PSQL.

Firebird Language Reference has quite comprehensive examples: https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-rdbms/

Comment: Also, it is very likely this needs to be a `for select ... into` rather than a singleton `select ... into`.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems with your code (as also mentioned by [user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13964273/user13964273)):

1. Statements in Firebird PSQL (its procedural SQL dialect) need to be terminated with a semicolon.
2. In PSQL, you cannot simply select, you need to select into variables or output parameters so you can use those in your stored procedure and/or return them to the caller of the procedure. See the [`INTO` section](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-select-into) of the `SELECT` documentation.

In addition, you also have the following things to consider

3. A `select` statement in PSQL can produce at most one row (a "singleton select"), while I think it's likely your statement will produce multiple rows. You will probably need to use [`for select`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-forselect) instead to iterate over the result of the query.
4. If you need to return rows to the caller, you need to add a [`RETURNS` clause](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-proc-create) with the desired columns (output parameters) and populate them with `INTO` or calculations in your procedural code.
5. If you want to return multiple rows, you'll need to add a [`SUSPEND` statement](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-suspend) when a row needs to be returned to the called. This makes the procedure [*selectable*](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-storedprocs-selectable) instead of [*executable*](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-storedprocs-executable).
6. Depending on how you execute the stored procedure DDL, you may need to configure your query tool to [switch statement terminators](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-sidebar01) (NOTE: this link is specific to Firebird ISQL, but third-party Firebird tools have similar options, sometimes even the same).

And as user13964273 said, it might be helpful to look at the examples in the [`PROCEDURE` section](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-procedure) of the DDL chapter and the [Procedural SQL (PSQL) Statements chapter](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql).